# Hello, i want to deploy a node webpack bundled app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, webpack

webpack always bundles as it does on a local environment. i don't know if it is normal.

A bit of my heroku log

```
-----> Node.js app detected
   
-----> Creating runtime environment
   
   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
   NODE_ENV=staging
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
   NODE_VERBOSE=false
   
-----> Build
   ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully. //This is coming from webpack after compiling app.
```

Below indicates that my deloyment to heroku failed.

```
-----> Timed out running buildpack Node.js
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create a .gitignore file and add your .env file to be ignored by git.

then you can deploy and set up your environment variables on the server.   you can do this either in the heroku ui under settings in your deployment folder or directly through your command prompt using the command "heroku config:set ENV_VARIABLE=something."

you can then run "heroku config" to see what variables have been stored.